# Connect to rest Api Azure

Tags: api, rest, azure, authentication, token

I would like to see an example of the set of messages that I need to authenticate the rest Api Azure , ie the get and post specified in this list but examples. The web page is 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/partnercenter/dn974935.aspx
https://azure.microsoft.com/es-es/documentation/articles/resource-manager-api-authentication/

Comment: If possible, please detail your question.

Comment: I connect with azure api thanks to the help of Microsoft, with this I managed to make calls to Azure api from iOS application. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-reference-oauth-code/

Answer (score 1):

There are two blogs which shows how to authenticate the REST API with ARM via get the access token and use the token to authorize a REST call.

1. For C#, please see [How to call the Azure Resource Manager REST API from C#](https://msftstack.wordpress.com/2016/01/03/how-to-call-the-azure-resource-manager-rest-api-from-c/).
2. For Java, please see [Authenticating Azure Resource Management REST API requests using Java](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/06/23/authenticating-azure-resource-management-rest-api-requests-using-java/).

Meanwhile, you can refer to Azure samples about Azure AD via access https://github.com/Azure-Samples?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=active-directory.

Hope it helps. Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, got what I wanted thanks to this help.https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-reference-oauth-code/

Comment: @JorgeFerreroLinacero Good. Thanks for your sharing.